# How to get rid of git stuff from bash Liquid prompt in conda environment?

Tags: bash, anaconda, conda

After creating a new virtual environment in anaconda/conda I've found that I have this ridiculously long prompt that has a bunch of git information in it.  Besides taking 2/3 of a line on my terminal, it lags by a few seconds every time I hit enter, presumably because it is re-analyzing for changes.  How can I get rid if this and go back to normal?  There's nothing in my bashrc that has anything to do with this.  It appears to be related to "liquid prompt".

Comment: Quick googling gets me [`LP_DISABLED_VCS_PATHS`](https://liquidprompt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html#LP_DISABLED_VCS_PATHS) as something to try; did you check the Liquid Prompt documentation?

Comment: I guess I was hoping not to go down a rabbit hole of fighting with this prompt program if the whole thing could be sidestepped.  If needed, I can try to make a custom liquidpromptrc.  I'm really surprised this is the default behavior of conda.  Even if it wasn't slow, the prompt is obnoxiously long.

Comment: `PS1='\$ '` assigns a really basic prompt; you can take it from there instead if you like. A slightly less basic prompt is `PS1='\w\$ '`